# Windows screencopy .net api not working as expected due to scaling issue

Tags: .net, rdp

Using the following I am able to take a screenshot of the current window into a bitmap object

```
Function ScreenShotWindow() As Bitmap
    Dim bmpScreenshot As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)

    Using g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot)
        g.CopyFromScreen(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y, 0, 0, Me.Size)
        Return bmpScreenshot
    End Using
End Function
```

(I've rewritten the above sample to simplify it, so there may be a syntax error, or two)

This technique works fine using my PC, or other PCs, when run from the console. However, when I execute the same code via RDP, the image is 'chopped', by which I mean the bitmap is smaller than the window and is missing some of the bottom and right of the window. This occurs consistently when connected via RDP.

So, it would seem I should be taking a scaling factor into account and going about the task in a slightly different way. All the above values refer to the number of pixels, which I would have thought apply the same regardless, but it seems not.

I've tried searching for scaling related documentation but no luck. I'm probably searching for the wrong thing.

Anyone know what I should be doing or what I should be looking at in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Control.DrawToBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) method.

I have tested the following code with both local and remote desktop machines and it works fine. Use it in your `Form` class.

```
Sub SaveWindowScreenshot(outputPath As String)
    Using bmp = New Bitmap(Width, Height)
        DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height))
        bmp.Save(outputPath)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately  DrawToBitmap doesn't work as it takes it starting point as the corner of the currently active window, thus 'new rectangle (0,0,100,100)' will return the top left corner of the application executing the function whereas I'm trying to take a screencopy of they whole desktop. As far as I can tell there isn't any way to get it to work with the whole screen.

Comment: But you say you want to take a screenshot of the *current window* in the question? My code works also when the active Window is maximized.

Comment: apologies, I didn't see your answer. I did indeed say  current window. My bad. I don't know why I used that phrasing. I'm taking screenshots of different parts of the screen. One of the things I need to do is to see which window has popped up and is overlapping the main one - which could be a status or error window launched by some other application.